# Firebase delay after checking connection

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Method checks connection with some delay. Namely if we are connected to the internet when we run app we will first receive message that we are "not connected" after milliseconds will receive proper answer that we are "connected". This delay in my case is crucial because i would like to inform user that he have to turn on internet just once to upload data from firebase database but if it is already turned on the message looks silly. Any advice?

Logcat message:

```
02-22 22:39:09.562 15945-15945/com.example.robert.aplikacjaitp D/BaseActivity: onDataChange on MainActivity: not connected
02-22 22:39:10.480 15945-15945/com.example.robert.aplikacjaitp D/BaseActivity: onDataChange on MainActivity: connected
```

method that runs in onCreate
[Old Version]:

```
void isConnected(){

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    connectedRef = new Firebase("https://testowa-baza-59b76.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
    application = new Application();

     mFacultiesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.KIERUNKI);
     mFacultiesReference.keepSynced(true);

    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new FirebaseDatabaseConnectionHandler());
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange on MainActivity: connected");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange on MainActivity: not connected");
                dataProcessingAlert();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[New Version] With upgraded Firebase SDK

```
 void isConnected(){

     connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://testowa-baza-59b76.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
     application = new Application();

     mFacultiesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.KIERUNKI);
     mFacultiesReference.keepSynced(true);

     connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
             if (connected) {
                 application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new FirebaseDatabaseConnectionHandler());
                 Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange on MainActivity: connected");
             } else {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange on MainActivity: not connected");
                 dataProcessingAlert();
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });
}
```

Comment: You're using a *very* old version of the Firebase SDK.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for noticing that I am working firebase for some time and just didn't realize about new version. However upgrading solution to newest one still does not solve the problem.

Comment: Could you show your updated code?  It will look different than what you have now.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited

Comment: So it sounds like what you're saying is that you want the SDK to connect faster?  You can't really force that issue.  All you can do is try to build your UI to compensate for that delay.